# WebPack error Module Not Found in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2017

When I run this command:

```
 node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod
--display-error-details
```

I get this error:

> ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\src\EduSmart\ClientApp' resolve
>   './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\src\EduSmart\ClientApp' using description file:
>   C:\src\EduSmart\package.json (relative path: ./ClientApp) Field
>   'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using
>   description file: C:\src\EduSmart\package.json (relative path:
>   ./ClientApp) using description file: C:\src\EduSmart\package.json
>   (relative path:
>   ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ngfactory) no extension
>   Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>   C:\src\EduSmart\$$_gendir\ClientApp\app\app.browser.module.ngfactory
>   doesn't exist .js Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>   configuration
>   C:\src\EduSmart\$$_gendir\ClientApp\app\app.browser.module.ngfactory.js
>   doesn't exist .ts Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias
>   configuration
>   C:\src\EduSmart\$$_gendir\ClientApp\app\app.browser.module.ngfactory.ts
>   doesn't exist as directory

**package.Json:**

```
{ 
"name": "EduSmart", 
"private": true, 
"version": "0.0.0", 
"scripts": { 
"test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js" 
}, 
"devDependencies": { 
"@angular/animations": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.0", 
"@angular/common": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/compiler": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/core": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/forms": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/http": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5", 
"@angular/router": "4.2.5", 
"@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0", 
"@types/chai": "4.0.1", 
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53", 
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0", 
"angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5", 
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2", 
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1", 
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1", 
"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1", 
"bootstrap": "3.3.7", 
"chai": "4.0.2", 
"css": "2.2.1", 
"css-loader": "0.28.4", 
"es6-shim": "0.35.3", 
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9", 
"expose-loader": "0.7.3", 
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2", 
"file-loader": "0.11.2", 
"html-loader": "0.4.5", 
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1", 
"jasmine-core": "2.6.4", 
"jquery": "3.2.1", 
"json-loader": "0.5.4", 
"karma": "1.7.0", 
"karma-chai": "0.1.0", 
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0", 
"karma-cli": "1.0.1", 
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0", 
"karma-webpack": "2.0.3", 
"preboot": "4.5.2", 
"raw-loader": "0.5.1", 
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.10", 
"rxjs": "5.4.2", 
"style-loader": "0.18.2", 
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5", 
"typescript": "2.4.1", 
"url-loader": "0.5.9", 
"webpack": "2.5.1", 
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2", 
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0", 
"zone.js": "0.8.12" 
}, 
"dependencies": { 
"@types/auth0-js": "^8.11.2", 
"auth0-js": "^9.2.3", 
"enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0", 
"es6-promise": "^4.2.4", 
"promise-polyfill": "7.1.0", 
"webpack-sources": "^1.1.0" 
} 
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Angular Template

**using the following versions:**

- Angular CLI: 1.7.0
- Node: 9.5.0
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 4.2.5
- typescript - 2.4.1

**I have tried :**

1. npm install promise-polyfill --save --save-exact
2. npm install enhanced-resolve@3.3.0
3. Deleted node_modules and reinstalled with npm install

Comment: Did you try npm install --save-dev webpack?

Comment: what does your webpack config look like? In particular the section on the Angular compiler. Does this only happen when you try to do AOT?

Comment: @olore, not sure what you are referring to, here is source code https://github.com/rberger247/EduSmart

Comment: I tried pulling down your repo and had so many other errors I couldn't even get this the error you describe. Sorry. Also this looks exactly like this question you asked already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897443/angular-4-webpack-config-error-cant-find-module-ngfactory

Comment: @olore thanks for the effort, I am moving back to angularjs for the moment, the headache involved with angular 2+ has not been worth it for me.